# AutoHotkey / Python Windows POST message

Tags: python, autohotkey

i have set autohotkey to send a ControlMessage to a background windwow, it works as intended and clicks the area successfully.

I simulated the function in python and Spy++ says the EXACT same message is sent to the window, but the click doesnt register on the target button

Spy++ Log for AHK script:

00000000000211B4 P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:396 yPos:196
00000000000211B4 P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:396 yPos:196

Spy++ Log for Python Script:

00000000000211B4 P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:396 yPos:196
00000000000211B4 P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:396 yPos:196

Is there some more backend business going on with autohotkey that im yet to find in logging? seems like python cant interact with the exact same message posting

Python Code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL


PostMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.PostMessageW
PostMessage.argtypes = [HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM]
PostMessage.restype = BOOL


WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201
WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202

hwnd = HWND(0x00000000000211B4)



x, y = 396, 196
lParam = LPARAM((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF))


PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WPARAM(0x0001), lParam)  


PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, WPARAM(0x0000), lParam)
```